# TeX Live's texlive.profile isn't generated automatically

Tags: texlive, texlive-2018

- Platform: macOS Mojave 10.14.2
- TeX Live version: 2018
- install-tl revision: 49210

I'm installing TeX Live to macOS like:

```
$ # Download an installer
$ curl -O http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz # <- you can use any mirror site you like
$ # Extract the installer
$ tar xvf install-tl-unx.tar.gz
$ # Run the installer
$ cd install-tl-20190115 # <- this dir name depends on the execution datetime
$ ./install-tl
```

The normal, interactive installation itself has been done with no error but a profile file named `texlive.profile` was not generated under `tlpkg` directory though `./install-tl -help` says:

> After a normal installation has finished, a profile for that exact installation is written to the file "tlpkg/texlive.profile".

I want to use that file in my automation script. Does anyone know about this issue or is this a mere bug?

Comment: Where did you install TeX Live? Where are you searching for tlmgr/texlive.profile? Just as a suggestion, most folks install MacTeX which installs a full, preconfigured TeX Live (2018 presently) and sets up a data structure that has a link, `/Library/TeX/texbin`, to the TeX binaries and also appends that link to the PATH variable.

Comment: No idea why it would fail to do that. From installing BasicTeX, I have it at `/usr/local/texlive/2018basic/tlpkg/texlive.profile`.

Comment: @HerbSchulz @AdamMaxwell Thank you two for answering this rapidly. I had misunderstood the location of `tlpkg/texlive.profile`. I'd thought that `tlpkg/texlive.profile` is created under the installer directory extracted from `install-tl-unx.tar.gz`. I'll self-answer this question and mark this as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had misunderstood the location of `texlive.profile`. The file is created under `tlpkg` directory in the installation directory such as `/usr/local/texlive/2018/`, not in the installer directory extracted from tar file.